# How to concatenate two lists?

Tags: list

Sorry, but elisp is not my best. 
I need to combine two lists of strings in this way:

```
("a" "b" "c") + ("d" "e" "f") -> ("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f")
```

Well, the order is not important, so I wrote this code:

```
(while lista
  (add-to-list 'listb (car lista)) 
  (setq lista (cdr lista)))
```

It works, but I'm wondering if there's a function that already does this.

Any clue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See node [Building Lists](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html) of the Elisp manual.

Comment: `append` is the correct answer here, but another (destructive) way to do it would be `(setcdr (last a) b)`.

Comment: Working on lists ? [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-concat-rest-lists) ! `(-concat '(1) '(2 3) '(4)) ;; => '(1 2 3 4)`

Comment: Never use `add-to-list` in Lisp code (it says this in the docstring). Instead, use `push`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can also just use append.

```
(append '("a" "b" "c") '("d" "e" "f"))
```

Comment: And, `(nconc '("a" "b" "c") '("d" "e" "f"))`

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed `append` seems better here.

Comment: nconc works but, if you store lists in variables, they will be modified by nconc. E.g. (let ((a '(1 2 3))  (b '(3 4 5))) (nconc a b)  a) will modify the a variable.

Comment: FYI `cl-concatenate` uses `append` when TYPE is `list`, so both answers are producing the same result.

Comment: Yess, it surely does the job. Many thanks to everybody for your help.

Answer (score 5):

> concatenate is an alias for ‘cl-concatenate’ in ‘cl.el’.
>
> (concatenate TYPE SEQUENCE...)
>
> Concatenate, into a sequence of type TYPE, the argument SEQUENCEs.

So for your example

```
(concatenate 'list '("a" "b" "c") '("d" "e" "f"))
```

Since it's defined in `cl` you may have to `(require 'cl)` first, otherwise you can use `cl-concatenate` which seems to be loaded by default.

Also, as pointed out by @phils `cl-concatenate` just calls [`append`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html#Building-Lists) when TYPE is `'list`, here's the source from `cl-extra.el`:

```el
(defun cl-concatenate (type &rest sequences)
  "Concatenate, into a sequence of type TYPE, the argument SEQUENCEs.
\n(fn TYPE SEQUENCE...)"
  (pcase type
    (`vector (apply #'vconcat sequences))
    (`string (apply #'concat sequences))
    (`list (apply #'append (append sequences '(nil))))
    (_ (error "Not a sequence type name: %S" type))))
```

So if you're only using lists, it's simpler to directly use `append`, as pointed out by @John Kitchin.

Finally, @lawlist mentionned [`nconc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rearrangement.html#Rearrangement):

> nconc is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.
>
> (nconc &rest LISTS)
>
> Concatenate any number of lists by altering them.
>   Only the last argument is not altered, and need not be a list.

What this means:

```
(nconc '("a" "b" "c") '("d" "e" "f"))
=> ("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f")

(setq l1 '("a" "b" "c")
      l2 '("d" "e" "f"))
(nconc l1 l2)
=> ("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f")
l1
=> ("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f")
l2
=> ("d" "e" "f")
```

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like it returns an error if 2nd and 3rd argument are variables and not explicit lists.

Comment: `(setq l1 '("a" "b" "c") l2 '("d" "e" "f")) (concatenate 'list l1 l2)` works ok.

Comment: @Daniele I suspect you were trying to *quote* the variables, which means they are not evaluated to their list values. (i.e. you want `varname` rather than `'varname`).

Comment: For completeness, I might as well mention the non-CL way of concatenating any type of sequence in Emacs>=25: `seq-concatenate` (after `(require 'seq)`), though this in turn just wraps `cl-concatenate`.